# How to increment alphanum value in Jmeter inside a loop counter

Tags: jmeter, load-testing, performance, blazemeter

I have requirement with increment value for each iteration and using loop controller.
I tried with the _V function and __intSum(${myVar},${__counter(,)},)}. it's incrementing only for digit and not for AlphaNum .
my paylody body like this.

```
{
"name":"BAN401"
}
```

I'm using like below.

```
{
"name":${__intSum(${FirstName},${__counter(,)},)}"
}
```

Answer (score 2):

1. Amend your body data as:

   ```
   {
   "name":"${FirstName}"
   }
   ```
2. Add [JSR223 PreProcessor](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#JSR223_PreProcessor) as a child of the request which payload you need to increment
3. Put the following code into "Script" area:

   ```
   def numericPart = (vars.get('FirstName') =~ /(\d+)/)[0][1] as int

   def incremented = numericPart + 1

   vars.put('FirstName', vars.get('FirstName').replace(numericPart as String, incremented as String))
   ```
4. That's it, each time the request will be called it will send an incremented value of the `${FirstName}` [JMeter Variable](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/functions.html)

Demo:

[image]

More information on Groovy scripting in JMeter: [Apache Groovy - Why and How You Should Use It](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/groovy-new-black)